# Idris pass proof to a function that arguments are LTE

Tags: ghc, idris, dependent-type, theorem-proving

I have a function which subtracts two `Nat`s. How do I prove that first argument I'm passing to it is actually smaller than the second

```
dummy : (k : Nat) -> (n : Nat) -> {auto smaller : LTE k n} -> Nat
dummy k n = n - k
```

I've tried couple of solutions which don't work

```
smallerThan : (k : Nat) -> (n : Nat) -> Maybe (LTE k n)
smallerThan Z k = Just (LTEZero {right=k})
smallerThan (S k) Z = Nothing
smallerThan (S k) (S n) = case isLTE k n of
                            Yes prf => Just prf
                            No contra => Nothing
```

```
smallerThan (S k) (S n) = case smallerThan k n of
                            Nothing => Nothing
                            Just lte => Just (cong lte)
```

I know that type of my hole `smallerThan (S k) (S n) = Just (?hole)` is `LTE (S k) (S n)` but how to properly use `fromLteSucc` or any other function in order to implement that?

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46507456/idris-proof-of-less-than) but that was solved without the proof I need.

Could you provide a hints of what I'm doing wrong and how to properly implement this kind of check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Just` case in your second attempt, you have thanks to recursion a proof that `LTE k n`, but need, as you state, `LTE (S k) (S n)`. You can find the missing step in two ways. [Search](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/reference/type-directed-search.html) in the REPL for a function of that type:

```
Idris> :search LTE k n -> LTE (S k) (S n)
= Prelude.Nat.LTESucc : LTE left right -> LTE (S left) (S right)
If n <= m, then n + 1 <= m + 1
```

or even simpler, use the [proof search](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/interactive.html#proofsearch) via REPL or the editor (I can just use `<space>p` to solve `?hole`, which is the best feature in Idris IMO!). That will also result in

```
 smallerThan (S k) (S n) = case smallerThan k n of
                             Nothing => Nothing
                             Just lte => Just (LTESucc lte)
```

Also, `isLTE` is `smallerThan` just with the more powerful `Dec` than `Maybe`, because in the negative case you get a proof that `k` is not smaller or equal to `n`. So `isLTE` is free of bugs, while `smallerThan` could just always return `Nothing`.

You can use that in the `dummy` calling function like:

```
foo : Nat -> Nat -> Nat
foo x y = case isLTE x y of
   Yes prf => dummy x y
   No contra => Z
```

Comment: Thanks for the search hint